# Matlab, converting datetime array in matrix

Tags: matlab, datetime, matrix

I have a datetime array that highlights the peaks of a function "datepeak", for every day in one year. I obtained it using a datetime array "date" and the array with the position of the peaks "position".

```
t1 = datetime(year,1,1,0,0,0);
t2 = datetime(year,12,31,23,59,0);
date = t1:minutes(1):t2;
datepeak=date(position);
```

I need to take the n number of peaks for the day 1 and transpose this array to the first row of the matrix, and so on. 
Since the number of peaks are not constants (min 3 max 4) I tried to initiate the matrix like this:

```
matrix=NaN(365,4)
```

Then I override the NaN of every row with this double for loop:

```
for i=1:365
v=datepeak(day(datepeak,'dayofyear')==i);
for c=1:length(v)
    matrix(i,c)=(v(c));
end
end
```

This loop works (I tried it with the peaks), but with datetime I get an error.

Here's an example to paste:

```
year=2016;
position=[128 458 950];
t1 = datetime(year,1,1,0,0,0);
t2 = datetime(year,12,31,23,59,0);
date = t1:minutes(1):t2;
datepeak=date(position);

matrix=NaN(365,4);

for i=1:365
v=datepeak(day(datepeak,'dayofyear')==i);
for c=1:length(v)
    matrix(i,c)=(v(c));
end
end
```

Comment: What error do you get ?

Comment: The following error occurred converting
from datetime to double:
Undefined function 'double' for input
arguments of type 'datetime'. To convert
from datetimes to numeric, first
subtract off a datetime origin, then
convert to numeric using the SECONDS,
MINUTES, HOURS, DAYS, or YEARS
functions.

Comment: The following error occurred converting
from datetime to double:
Undefined function 'double' for input
arguments of type 'datetime'. To convert
from datetimes to numeric, first
subtract off a datetime origin, then
convert to numeric using the SECONDS,
MINUTES, HOURS, DAYS, or YEARS
functions.

Comment: I think because the NaN matrix is expecting a double value

Comment: Do you absolutely need a 365x4 array ? Would a list of 365 elements, each of them containing the 3 or 4 peaks of the day be ok ?

Comment: By the way, i'll add it here as it does not appear in my answer. Do not loop when that's not necessary. For example, your inner loop should be replaced with `matrix(i,1:length(v)) = v;`. That's shorter, quicker and more readable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143569/discussion-between-g-j-and-scana).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `nan` array is of class `double` whereas `datepeak` is of class `datetime` so you can't store them in the same array. The way you represent your data should be driven by what you want to do with them later (and what is feasible). In your case, i'll assume that list 365 elements, containing the (any number) peak times of the day is ok.

```
year=2016;
position=[128 458 950];
t1 = datetime(year,1,1,0,0,0);
t2 = datetime(year,12,31,23,59,0);
date = t1:minutes(1):t2;
datepeak=date(position);

peaktimes_list = cell(365,1);

for i=1:365
    peaktimes_list{i} = datepeak(day(datepeak,'dayofyear')==i);
end
```

**EDIT** : For a 365x4 cell array, change the last part by :

```
peaktimes = cell(365,4);

for i=1:365
    v = datepeak(day(datepeak,'dayofyear')==i);
    nv = numel(v);
    peaktimes(i,1:nv) = num2cell(v);
end
```

When there are less than 4 values, the remaining columns will be empty.

Comment: Thank you
I have to create a table. Once I'll have the matrix with the datetime:

result=table(peak(:,1),datematrix(:,1),peak(:,2),datematrix(:,2),peak(:,3),datematrix(:,3),peak(:,4),datematrix(:,4));

Comment: I think you intended "peaktimes" and not "peaktimes_list" inside the loop.

Anyway it works fine. Thanks a lot